# Convert String to Date in Informix DB

Tags: sql, informix

I need to Convert a string say '12/12/2013 14:30:56.583' to be converted in Date Format like 2013-12-12 14:30:56.583 in Informix database.

I Used following function

```
to_date('12/12/2013 14:30:56.583',"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.")
```

But its not accepting Milliseconds , Milliseconds are important to the resulting value.

Answer (score 5):

The database version is important. The behaviour of %F was recently (11.70.xC8 and 12.10.xC2) changed. In previous versions the "." dot must probably be omitted as well as the "n" qualifier.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

If you check the manual you will see is missing the milliseconds at the string format.

source: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1542.htm

> %S Second as a 2-digit integer (00 through 61). The second value can
>   be up to 61 (instead of 59) to allow for the occasional leap second
>   and double leap second.
>
> %Fn The value of the fraction of a second, with precision specified by
>   the unsigned integer n. The default value of n is 2; the range of n is
>   0 ≤ n ≤ 5. This value overrides any width or precision that is
>   specified between the % and F characters.

So, this probably will work:

```
to_date('12/12/2013 14:30:56.583',"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%F3")
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not that familiar with Informix, but I think you may be able to use the standard to_date function to convert the string value to a date and then use an addMilliseconds function to add the milliseconds.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/informix/v121/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.netpr.doc%2Fids_net_093.htm